# Angular local reference issue in date picker

Tags: javascript, angular

I've a date picker component in my angular and Im trying to access it values using local reference.

Sadly the local reference is giving me undefined when I try to console them.

Provided datepicker , the function and trigger in order below

Using angular 7 for it

```
<app-date-picker #startingDate class="col-12 ">
              </app-date-picker>
```

```
datesCompare(sDate, eDate){
    console.log(sDate, eDate, '-------dates------')
  }


<input type="text" class="input-box" placeholder="Code" 
 (click)="datesCompare(startingDate, endingDate)">
```

Comment: Getting 
undefined undefined "-------dates------"
as console log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get HTML element like that:

```
<app-date-picker #startingDate class="col-12 ">
              </app-date-picker>
```

TypeScript:

```
@ViewChild('startingDate') startingDate; 

datesCompare(){
    console.log('startingDate:', this.startingDate )
}
```